# Convergence almost everywhere and absolute value

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Is it true that if $(f_n)$ converges almost everywhere to $f$ then $(\vert f_n \vert)$ converges also almost everywhere to $\vert f \vert$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that, if $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, then $|f_n(x)|\to |f(x)|$ using the same kinds of rules?

Comment: I would say yes, by using the continuity of the absolute value function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the "reverse triangle inequality",

$$|\, |f_n(x)| - |f(x)|\,|\le |f_n(x)-f(x)|\longrightarrow 0$$

a.e. as $n\rightarrow\infty$.